# How can I resolve the https proxy error message when attempting to connect to TFS Builds through Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: tfs, proxy, visual-studio-2015

We just upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and TFS 2015 in our organization.  I'm trying to connect to the Builds tab in Visual Studio 2015 Team Explorer and am getting the following error message in the Builds window:

> The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme.

I've tried adding the proxy to devenv.exe.config.  I've also tried adding various registry keys to my client machine to bypass the proxy when using local connections.  I tried using the tf.exe command to set up the proxy on TFS but received an error message about permissions.

Our TFS expert is looking into it from the server side but I can't seem to find another solution regarding this error message and TFS anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that our Xamarin trial's install was messing with our firewall by asking for proxy credentials and caused it to block TFS.  Uninstalling Xamarin fixed the issue.  I know it's a band-aid, but we aren't using Xamarin now and the solution worked.